# Mod rewrite with uppercase adds query string

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm using mod Rewrite to rewrite part of the URL to a query parameter

URLs are of the form

```
http://www.my_site.com/ABC
```

where ABC is the bit to force into a query parameter to my `index.php` in a sub directory

My `.htaccess` has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ directory/index.php?Site=$1 [L]
```

When I have a lowercase ABC e.g:

```
my_site.com/abc
```

the browser URL remains unchanged and the page works perfectly with abc being passed in the GET.

However, when ABC is UPPERCASE e.g:

```
my_site.com/ABC
```

the URL in the browser becomes:

```
my_site.com/ABC/?Site=ABC
```

It works OK and ABC is still in the `GET` parameter but it looks ugly!

Why does case affect this and can I make BOTH upper and lower case maintain the original URL?

Further note: I tried an example of a different server and it worked perfectly! Any ideas if there are server settings that could affect this?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Have you tried rewriting to `/directory/index.php?Site=$1` instead of `directory/index.php?Site=$1`?

Comment: No affect. I still got a browser URL that looked like mysite/ABC/?Site=ABC

Comment: Have you verified this is the rule that's actually being run? Try commenting it out and verifying that something changes.

Comment: the rule is being executed since it does take me to the right page with the right GET variable set perfectly.

Comment: Right, I'd suspect that too. I think it's probably worthwhile to verify that there isn't something else going on, though. At this point, I'd be trying to verify that it's being run. The rule looks correct to me -- it's possible that there's something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it - as sidoh said something else is going on.

If there is a directory on my server which is the same name as the parameter the mod_rewrite adds the query to the URL.

e.g.
If I've got a directory ABC on the server then using my mod_rewrite with www.domain.com/ABC results in the browser URL www.domain.com/ABC/Site=ABC - if no directory ABC all is fine and the URL remains www.domain.com/ABC (which is what I want).

Since I'm on Linux ABC is different to abc - which explains the apparent case sensitive nature of the behaviour.

Thanks to all for their inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean, the *[NC]* nocase flag? Which will make the rule be matched in a case-insensitive manner. Means, it will doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /directory/index.php?Site=$1 [NC]
```

---

I think, you want to rewrite a URL such */bigSMALL* into */directory/index.php?Site=BIGsmall*? If am I right, then the problem is in the program and not in URL remapping. However, in **MySQL** database, when you're getting the value of a query string for querying a `WHERE` value, it is match in a case-insensitive. Take a look at the picture:

[image: username = 'nAmE is case-insensitive']

Are you developing a website? If ever, then what DBMS are you using? Maybe, **MySQL**?

Comment: I don't think it should matter since the regex is case-insensitive anyway, right?

Comment: @sidoh If you want to rewrite a URL such _/bigSMALL_ into _/directory/index.php?Site=BIGsmall_, then the problem is in the program. Check my updates!

Comment: No - it purely the difference in the URL shown in teh Browser after the mod_rewrite is done - if its ABC I get /?site=ABC if I use abc I do not get any Query in the URL - but both pass the GET variable perfectly.

Comment: @Nimur What do you really want to happened?